# Missing JavaFX application class when using jPackage

Tags: java, javafx, jpackage

I'm getting the message "Missing JavaFX application class com.ponderwhy.pikeinventory.PikeInventory" after deploying with jPackage.
Using AdoptOpenJDK 16, JavaFx-16, WiX 3.11 on Windows 10. My application runs fine when I use the following JVM options file.

---

```
#  -classpath  aka -cp 
-cp D:/WS_Utility/PikeInventory/bin;D:/WS_Utility/Basic/bin;D:/WS_Utility/ancillary/bin;C:/Java/javafx-sdk-16/lib;C:/Java/controlsfx-jfx-13/controlsfx-11.0.2.jar

#  -modulepath  aka -p
-p C:/Java/javafx-sdk-16/lib;D:/WS_Utility/basic/bin;D:/WS_Utility/Ancillary/bin;D:/WS_Utility/PikeInventory/bin;C:/Java/controlsfx-jfx-13/controlsfx-11.0.2.jar

--add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH
--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-exports javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.runtime=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens   javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.css=ALL-UNNAMED

com.ponderwhy.pikeinventory.PikeInventory
```

---

When I use jPackage to build an.exe file using the following jPackage commands:

---

```
--type exe
--app-version 1.0.1
--description "Pike Inventory"
--name PikeInventory
--vendor PonderWhy
--verbose
--java-options -splash:$APPDIR//RockF7.jpg
--input D:/Dev/TrainInv/jPackage
--icon  D:/Dev/TrainInv/jPackage/LocoFront.ico

--main-jar PikeInventory.jar
--main-class com.ponderwhy.pikeinventory.PikeInventory
--module-path C:/Java/javafx-jmods-16;C:/Java/controlsfx-jfx-13;C:/Java/JDK-16/jmods;D:/Dev/TrainInv/jPackage
--add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web

--win-console
--win-dir-chooser
--win-menu
--win-menu-group PikeInventory
--win-shortcut
# --win-upgrade-uuid PkInv
```

---

I have the 2 environment variables set that I find some references to.
PATH_TO_FX=C:\Java\javafx-sdk-16\lib
PATH_TO_FX_MODS=C:\Java\javafx-jmods-16

All three of my projects, Basic, Ancillary and PikeInventory have module-info.class.
The jPackage builds, deploys and installs without error. My splash comes up then the missing class message.

I am at a loss at what to try next to resolve my problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Peter